# Determining the nature of roots

Tags: equation-solving

Here comes a simple scenario

```
fz = 8 (z + 18 A z + (8 - 48 A) z^3 + 16 z^5);
sol = Solve[fz == 0, z]
```

As we can see there are five roots. The root (0,0) is always present while the nature of the other four roots strongly depends on the numerical value of A. I found that when $A < -1/18$ we have two real and two purely imaginary roots. For $A > -1/18$ there are three cases:

(i) When $A \in (-1/18, A_1)$ we have 4 purely imaginary roots,

(ii) When $A \in (A_1, A_2)$ we have 4 complex roots,

(iii) When $A > A_2$ we have 4 real roots.

My question: How can I determine the exact values of $A_1$ and $A_2$, whiche delimit the three intervals?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: This really is more of a math question than a *Mathematica* question. In any event, [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2972804) might be of interest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Discriminant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Discriminant):

```
Solve[
    Discriminant[8 (z+18 A z+(8-48 A) z^3+16 z^5), z] == 0,
    A
]
```

> {{A -> -(1/18)}, {A -> -(1/18)}, {A -> -(1/18)}, {A -> 0}, {A -> 0}, {A -> 5/
>      6}, {A -> 5/6}}

Comment: Quick and elegant!

Answer (score 4):

```
fz = 8 (z + 18 A z + (8 - 48 A) z^3 + 16 z^5);
```

Solve for the real roots and the [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) for the root will tell you when it is real

As [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects

```
(solR = z /. Solve[fz == 0, z, Reals]) // Column
```

[image]

As radicals

```
(solR // ToRadicals) // Column
```

[image]

**EDIT:** For there to be four complex roots then `-1/8 < A < 5/6`. Further, for all of these four complex roots to be purely imaginary then `Re[z] == 0` and there must be `5` roots counting the root at `z == 0`.

```
Select[List @@ (Reduce[{fz == 0, Re[z] == 0, -1/8 < A < 5/6}, {A, z}] // 
    ToRadicals), Count[#, z == _, Infinity] == 5 &]
```

[image]

So the interval for four purely imaginary roots is `{-1/8, 0}`.

For example,

```
% /. A -> -0.05

(* {z == 0. + 0.0988028 I || z == 0. - 0.0988028 I || z == 0 || 
  z == 0. + 0.800149 I || z == 0. - 0.800149 I} *)
```

Comment: Hmmm, With this method we defined that $A_2 = 5/6$. But what about $A_1$?